# Getting tail of a list in Multiple Assignment in Groovy

Tags: list, groovy, destructuring

List Destructuring (Multiple Assignment) in Groovy can be used to bind values to variables from a list. For example:

```
def (first, second, third) = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
assert third == 3
```

Is there a syntactical way to achieve the following:

```
def (first, second, <rest>) = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
assert ​rest​ == [3,4,5,6]
```

If not, what is closest/grooviest way to achieve the same result, preferably in single expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is transform the list from six to three elements in the way that you describe. I.e. transform `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` to `[1,2,[3,4,5,6]]`. You probably also want this to be adjustable to any number of elements.

Here is a solution where a new method `reduce` is added to `List` which transforms the list in the proposed way:

```
List.metaClass.reduce = { int size -> delegate[0..size-2] + [delegate[size-1..-1]] }

def (first, second, rest) = [1,2,3,4,5,6].reduce(3)
assert first == 1
assert second == 2
assert rest == [3,4,5,6]
```

Edit: Last night, when going to sleep, I thought about using `with` to achieve this as a one liner. It's the same idea as above, though more cryptic (less readable) since the logic is inlined.

```
def (first, second, rest) = [1,2,3,4,5,6].with { it[0..1] + [it[2..-1]] }
assert first == 1
assert second == 2
assert rest == [3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use multiple assignments to achieve this. Here's one option:

```
def list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def first = list[0]
def second = list[1]
def rest = list[2..-1]
```

Comment: yeah, Thanks for answering. I should have been more clear in question (I have updated it now). I am looking for a single expression / destructuring approach, which can be easily generalized such that def (a,b,c...<n>) = [...]

Comment: @kunal I understand what you want, but it's just not possible to do this, because the multiple assignment syntax will only assign one element of a list to each variable

Answer (score 2):

Closest I could reach is:

Option 1: If toying with metaClass sounds like good idea:

```
List.metaClass.destructure = { ...n->
   n.collect { delegate[it] }
}

def (a, b, rest) = [1,2,3,4].destructure(0, 1, 2..-1)
```

Options 2. Otherwise a good old method to the rescue:

```
def destructure (list,...n) {
    n.collect { list[it] }
}

def (a, b, rest) = destructure([1,2,3,4], 0, 1, 2..-1)
```

​
Option 3. An inline but little ugly solution

```
def (a, b, rest) = [0, 1, 2..-1].collect { [1,2,3,4][it] }
```

All of above pass the criteria

```
assert rest​ == ​[3,4]​
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the solutions already offered that use `with()` + closure and `collect()` + closure. This solution uses only a closure with varargs:

```
def (first, second, rest) = { ... a -> a[0..1] + [a[2..-1]]} (1,2,3,4,5,6)

println first
println second
println rest
```